# What's the difference between Duby and Juby and why would I need either of them?

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

According to [Charles Nutter](http://blog.headius.com/2009/08/introducing-surinx.html), **Duby** is

> a static-typed language with Ruby's
>   syntax and Java's type system. Duby
>   supports all Ruby's literals, uses
>   local type inference (only argument
>   types *must* be declared), and runs as
>   fast as Java (because it produces
>   nearly identical bytecode). But with
>   the advent of invokedynamic, Duby
>   needed a playmate.

**1. What's invokedynamic and why does Duby "need a playmate"?**

**Juby**, on the other hand, is

> intended to be basically like Duby, in
>   that it uses Java's types and Ruby's
>   syntax. But it takes advantage of the
>   new invokedynamic opcode to be 100%
>   dynamic. Juby is a dynamic Duby, or
>   perhaps a dynamic Java with Ruby
>   syntax. It's not hard to comprehend.

Actually it is hard to comprehend.

**2. Could someone elaborate a little bit more on what this distinction is about?**

**3. Why do we need (*need!*) another Ruby-related language?** Or, rather, two more Ruby-related languages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mirah (formerly Duby) exists, because static typing can result in dramatically improved performance with Java/Hotspot.  Surinx (formerly Juby) is the same thing, except that it also takes advantage of a new performance feature that is coming in JDK7 to enhance performance even further.

The performance feature is commonly called "invokedynamic", and a good explanation is available on [Nutter's blog](http://blog.headius.com/2008/09/first-taste-of-invokedynamic.html) as well.

Comment: But why not just add the performance feature to Duby? Why an entirely new language? If we create a new language every time we want to add a feature . . . you know where I'm going.

Comment: @Michael: I suspect that its driven by a desire for experimentation and a lack of availability of invokedynamic.  Duby can be useful now (pre JDK7), Juby can be useful for JDK7+.

Comment: Duby and Surinx are *not* "the same thing"! In fact, they are pretty much opposites, in some sense: Duby is statically typed, Surinx is dynamically typed. This entire answer is more or less completely made up. And not even well.

Comment: @ - Jörg - Nutter's terminology here is a bit confusing to me. Straight from the referenced page: "Juby is intended to be basically like Duby, in that it uses Java's types and Ruby's syntax." If they are polar opposites, why does he say it is "basically like Duby"? I think they really are pretty similar... duby uses local type inference (except for method invocations). Juby is dynamically typed, including method invocations via invokedynamic.

Comment: @Telemachus, or even "Scooby Dooby Doo" :-)

Answer (score 50):

I'm going to answer the questions out of order, starting with the simplest one:

> 2. Could someone elaborate a little bit more on what this distinction is about?

[Duby](http://Duby.Kenai.Com/) is statically typed, [Surinx](https://GitHub.Com/Headius/Surinx/) (which is the final name for what was for a short amount of time called [Juby](https://GitHub.Com/Headius/Surinx/)) is dynamically typed. That's already all there is to it.

Actually, there is one small detail as a consequence of this: [Surinx](https://GitHub.Com/Headius/Surinx/) syntax is a strict subset of [Ruby](http://Ruby-Lang.Org/) syntax, i.e. every syntactically valid [Surinx](https://GitHub.Com/Headius/Surinx/) program is also a syntactically valid [Ruby](http://Ruby-Lang.Org/) program. [Duby](http://Duby.Kenai.Com/) OTOH is *almost* a syntactic subset, except for its mandatory method parameter type annotations:

```
def foo(bar => Integer, baz => String) => Array
  # ...
end
```

That's illegal in [Ruby](http://Ruby-Lang.Org/).

> 3. Why do we need (need!) another [Ruby](http://Ruby-Lang.Org/)-related language?

First off: other than syntactic similarity, these languages are in no way, shape or form related to [Ruby](http://Ruby-Lang.Org/).

So, why did [Charles Oliver Nutter](http://Blog.Headius.Com/) create [Duby](http://Duby.Kenai.Com/)? He is the lead developer of the [JRuby](http://JRuby.Org/) [Ruby](http://Ruby-Lang.Org/) implementation, which is an implementation of the [Ruby programming language](http://Ruby-Lang.Org/) for the JVM. Like most [Ruby](http://Ruby-Lang.Org/) implementations, it is written in the dominant programming language of the underlying platform: [MRI](https://GitHub.Com/RubySpec/MatzRuby/tree/ruby_1_8/), [YARV](https://GitHub.Com/RubySpec/MatzRuby/tree/trunk/) and [tinyrb](http://Code.MACournoyer.Com/tinyrb/) are implemented 100% in C, [MacRuby](http://MacRuby.Org/) mostly in C with a bit of Objective-C, [Ruby.NET](http://RubyDotNetCompiler.GoogleCode.Com/) and [IronRuby](http://IronRuby.Net/) 100% in C#, [HotRuby](http://HotRuby.Accelart.Jp/) in [ECMAScript](http://WWW.ECMA-International.Org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), [Red Sun](https://GitHub.Com/JonathanBranam/RedSun/) in ActionScript, [Cardinal](https://GitHub.Com/Cardinal/Cardinal/) in PIR and NQP and so on. (The only [Ruby](http://Ruby-Lang.Org/) implementations that contain a significant amount of [Ruby](http://Ruby-Lang.Org/) code are [Rubinius](http://Rubini.us/) (about 70% [Ruby](http://Ruby-Lang.Org/), 30% C++) and [MagLev](http://MagLev.GemStone.Com/) (unknown amounts of [Ruby](http://Ruby-Lang.Org/) and [Smalltalk](http://Smalltalk.Org/)).) And naturally, [XRuby](http://XRuby.Com/) and [JRuby](http://JRuby.Org/) are implemented 100% in Java.

Now, the funny thing is, [Charlie](http://Blog.Headius.Com/) came to [Ruby](http://Ruby-Lang.Org/), because he didn't like his day job, doing Java development. And now, he *still* writes Java code all day long! Of course, he doesn't like that, and so he was looking for another programming language in which to implement the core of [JRuby](http://JRuby.Org/). One option would certainly be to just write it all in [Ruby](http://Ruby-Lang.Org/), but with [metacircular implementations](http://C2.Com/cgi/wiki/?MetaCircularEvaluator) there usually comes a point of diminishing returns, where the implementations degenerates into academic masturbation. It would certainly make sense to rewrite the libraries, the ahead-of-time compiler (actually, [that's already being done](https://GitHub.Com/JRuby/JRuby/blob/master/tool/compiler2.rb)) and some of the core classes in [Ruby](http://Ruby-Lang.Org/), but some parts of the engine core are better written in something closer to the execution model of the JVM itself.

[Charlie](http://Blog.Headius.Com/) was looking at the available options: [Scala](http://Scala-Lang.Org/), [Groovy](http://Groovy.CodeHaus.Org/), [Fan](http://FanDev.Org/), [Clojure](http://Clojure.Org/), [Nice](http://Nice.SourceForge.Net/), but all of them had a significant disadvantage: a fairly large language runtime. The size of the [JRuby](http://JRuby.Org/) runtime is already a big problem in terms of memory consumption and startup latency (especially compared to [MRI](https://GitHub.Com/RubySpec/MatzRuby/tree/ruby_1_8/) or [YARV](https://GitHub.Com/RubySpec/MatzRuby/tree/trunk/) and even more so if you actually include the JVM itself in your measurements), and rewriting it in a language that adds its *own* runtime to that weight is simply a no-go. Unfortunately, there was no programming language which satisfied the two basic criteria [Charlie](http://Blog.Headius.Com/) was looking for: no runtime and compiles to JVM bytecode that is at least as efficient as the equivalent Java.

So, he decided to create his own. The reason why he chose to use a syntax similar to [Ruby](http://Ruby-Lang.Org/), is actually quite simple: he didn't need to write a parser for it, [Duby](http://Duby.Kenai.Com/) just uses [JRuby](http://JRuby.Org/)'s already existing parser with one minor modification to support method parameter type annotations. (Actually, he also likes [Ruby](http://Ruby-Lang.Org/)'s syntax, that was of course also a factor.)

As you know the syntax is actually the least important part of a programming language. (Its irrelevance isn't always *obvious* from the [amount of arguing about it](http://Google.Com/search?q=Python+indentation+sucks), but that's just because syntax is the only thing you can argue about without having to actually understand what you are talking about.) Much more important than the syntax is the type system and the evaluation semantics. And here comes the trick: [Duby](http://Duby.Kenai.Com/) doesn't have either! It *only* has syntax! It's like a parasite: it simply "borrows" the type system and semantics from its underlying platform. That means that on the JVM, [Duby](http://Duby.Kenai.Com/)'s type system *is* the Java type system, and [Duby](http://Duby.Kenai.Com/)'s semantics *are* Java's semantics. To put it another way: [Duby](http://Duby.Kenai.Com/) isn't a programming language *at all*, rather it is "just" an alternative syntax for Java.

That means that there is no mapping, no conversion overhead and no speed difference between [Duby](http://Duby.Kenai.Com/) and Java. And that means that the internals of [JRuby](http://JRuby.Org/) could be written in [Duby](http://Duby.Kenai.Com/), without losing any features.

So, that's [Duby](http://Duby.Kenai.Com/).

In order to explain [Surinx](https://GitHub.Com/Headius/Surinx/), I'll first answer your first question:

> 1. What's [invokedynamic](http://JCP.Org/en/jsr/detail?id=292) and why does [Duby](http://Duby.Kenai.Com/) "need a playmate"?

[`invokedynamic`](http://JCP.Org/en/jsr/detail?id=292) is specifically a new bytecode that is going to be added to the 3rd edition of the JVM specification and that is going to be released in JDK7. However, more generally [`invokedynamic`](http://JCP.Org/en/jsr/detail?id=292) is usually used as a stand-in to refer to a whole bunch of features, of which the *actual* [`invokedynamic` bytecode](http://JCP.Org/en/jsr/detail?id=292) is only one, that are currently being developed under the umbrella of [JSR-292 "Supporting Dynamically Typed Languages on the Java Platform"](http://JCP.Org/en/jsr/detail?id=292). And even more generally, the name [`invokedynamic`](http://JCP.Org/en/jsr/detail?id=292) is used as a moniker for the general change of strategy both in Sun and in the JCP as a whole to turn the Java platform into a general purpose language platform for all sorts of languages.

The specific purpose of [JSR-292](http://JCP.Org/en/jsr/detail?id=292) (which is what [Charlie](http://Blog.Headius.Com/) alludes to in his blog post), is to make dynamic method dispatch faster – indeed, almost as fast as *static* dispatch in Java, at least in the best case.

[Surinx](https://GitHub.Com/Headius/Surinx/) is a dynamically typed programming language which basically does the same thing as [Duby](http://Duby.Kenai.Com/): like [Duby](http://Duby.Kenai.Com/), it *also* has *only* syntax, like [Duby](http://Duby.Kenai.Com/), it *also* used the Java type system. But *unlike* [Duby](http://Duby.Kenai.Com/), it does *not* use *Java's* method invocation semantics, instead it uses [*`invokedynamic`s*](http://JCP.Org/en/jsr/detail?id=292) method invocation semantics. IOW: it is dynamically typed and uses dynamic dispatch.

So, that's [Surinx](https://GitHub.Com/Headius/Surinx/).

Now, I can answer the second half of your third question:

> 3. Why do we need (need!) […] two more Ruby-related languages?

I already answered for [Duby](http://Duby.Kenai.Com/), here's the answer for [Surinx](https://GitHub.Com/Headius/Surinx/): it's what [Groovy](http://Groovy.CodeHaus.Org/) *should* have been – a lightweight (actually, *zero*-weight) dynamic expressive scripting language for the JVM. Also, it is currently the simplest way to play around with the inner workings of [`invokedynamic`](http://JCP.Org/en/jsr/detail?id=292). (The current development snapshots of [JRuby 1.4](http://JRuby.Headius.Com:8080/hudson/job/jruby-dist/) also support it, but that's a much more complex project.)

---

Two things I left out: [Duby](http://Duby.Kenai.Com/) actually uses local variable type inference, so, unlike Java, you only have to declare the types of method parameters, but everything *inside* a method will be type-inferred.

And secondly, both [Duby](http://Duby.Kenai.Com/) and [Surinx](https://GitHub.Com/Headius/Surinx/) are not actually tied to the JVM. Since they just steal their semantics and type systems from the underlying platform, they can be ported almost anywhere, where you have a rough mapping from [Ruby](http://Ruby-Lang.Org/) syntax to platform concepts. Off the top of my head, I could imagine ports of [Duby](http://Duby.Kenai.Com/) to C, C++, Objective-C (iPhone, anyone?), [D](http://DigitalMars.Com/d/), [CLI](http://WWW.ECMA-International.Org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.html) and ActionScript and ports of [Surinx](https://GitHub.Com/Headius/Surinx/) to the [DLR](http://CodePlex.Com/DLR/), [Smalltalk](http://Smalltalk.Org/), [Parrot](http://ParrotCode.Org/), [ECMAScript](http://WWW.ECMA-International.Org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), [Python](http://Python.Org/), [Perl](http://Perl.Com/), [PHP](http://PHP.Net/) and Objectice-C. In fact, there are already the beginnings of a [C port of Duby](http://Kenai.Com/projects/duby/sources/mercurial/content/lib/duby/c/compiler.rb).

Comment: Thanks for such a well-structured, comprehensive answer

Comment: "As you know the syntax is actually the least important part of a programming language."

The irony of this is overwhelming in a comment espousing the virtues of duby's syntactic changes on top of java's semantics ;)

Comment: @jshen: Glad that someone caught the irony :-) However, it's actually a bit more than just syntax: I mentioned type inference in the post. There's also closures. And, as of today, Duby also supports dynamic dispatch (IOW Duby is the new Surinx). None of those three is available in Java. Also, while syntax doesn't change the expressive power of the language, it *does* change the "expressive convenience". I admit I tend to exaggerate when trying to define Duby: many people think it's just another implementation of Ruby, and I wanted to be as clear as possible that Duby is very far from Ruby.

Comment: Jorg, adding a couple of your answers (just snippets with links here) to my morning blog post. Thanks for your excellent answers.

Comment: @Mark Essel: BTW: As of two weeks ago, dynamic typing support has been merged into Duby, thus making Surinx obsolete. Also, there has been lots of work done on Duby by some Google guys, for doing Google App Engine and Android development. (There's been a couple of videotaped talks on that topic.)

Comment: I'm all over those Jorg (watched a great video by Ola Bini), and have been enjoying the attention people have given to Ruby/Ruby-Like optimization work and Java compatibility. For numerically intensive processing the MRI isn't quite fast enough, but the long term expressive ability of Ruby is unmatched in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

Just came across this, straight [from Charles himself](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/11/duby-surinx) which partly addresses the question (re: the difference between them):

> Which brings me to the future of
>   Surinx. It's even simpler than the
>   future of Duby: the two will merge. As
>   I have worked on both Surinx and Duby,
>   it has become apparent to me that
>   they're essentially the same language
>   with different dispatch mechanisms and
>   type declaration requirements. And
>   since Duby could easily treat untyped
>   or dynamic-typed expressions as
>   requiring dynamic invocation, there's
>   no reason Surinx shouldn't just be
>   assimilated as a feature of Duby.

Comment: As of today that merge has happened.

Answer (score 3):

As with languages, we don't create them because we 'need' them. People create them for whatever reason and if unless we need them, they remain obscure.

There's plenty of obscure languages out there; they're fun to play with but probably not something you'd want to do a real project in.

Comment: Case in point:  Brainfuck:  >[-]>[-]<<[->+>+<<]  (which sets the memory locations 1 and 2 to the contents of memory location 0)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that at some point I may be able to prototype a piece of code in Plain Ol' Dynamic Ruby and, when it works but needs to be significantly faster, port it, with relatively minor levels of pain, to a close relation that will compile to optimised JITted Java bytecode. Or quite possibly IronRuby#.NET, [Sapphire](http://www.sapphiresteel.com/The-Sapphire-Language) or something else.

Graphic manipulation, heavy mathematics, AI, stuff like that. I suspect I'd have some fun doing that...

Comment: I thought that was the advantage that JRuby provided more or less. I mean, it's not compiled, but the JRuby interpreter is significantly faster than MRI (don't know about 1.9 though). Maybe what you're saying is that this is one step beyond this - even faster than the fastest possible interpreter could be.

Comment: That's my understanding (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JRuby#Performance) - what Charles is talking about now is a family(?) of Ruby-derived languages that will deliver performance roughly the same as pura JITted Java. Fast, in other words.